# How to exclude x-pack from getting compiled while compiling elasticsearch source code in eclipse

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, xpack

I am trying to compile elasticsearch source code in eclipse,but i want to exclude x-pack from this compilation.
Any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a line in `settings.gradle` which specifies subProjects.
One of them is `addSubProjects(‘’, new File(rootProject.projectDir, ‘x-pack’))`

I suspect that you need to comment this line and build with `./gradlew assemble` command

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\mkumaru\Desktop\elasticsearch-master\elasticsearch-master\build.gradle' line: 275

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'elasticsearch-master'.
> Project :x-pack:test:feature-aware not found.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to stop x-pack by commenting few lines in build.gradle .
But i dont want to remove or comment any code.
So is there any gradle command to exclude x-pack in compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to exclude x-pack by commenting few lines.
But i want to achieve it without commenting any of those lines.
I think there has to be some gradle command to exclude x-pack dependency.